# Flutter widget to grow and shrink according to child size?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is there a widget, or a simple way, to have a container that animates it's size, in response to its child?

So something like this might animate smoothly between open and closed builders

```
ResizingBox(
  openBuilder: (_) => FlutterLogo(size: 200),
  closedBuilder: (_) => FlutterLogo(size: 50),
),
```

Essentially looking for the expanding/contracting behavior of `ExpandingPanel` but, inside of a Stack, and expanding both Vt and Hz: https://youtu.be/2aJZzRMziJc?t=99

Comment: `Container` by default already matches its `child`'s size, so if the child widget animates in size (it is the case for `FlutterLogo`), the `Container` would automatically resize too.

Comment: Right, but I don't want the child to have to animate, I want the parent container to animate to match the child.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the logo inside an `AnimatedContainer` widget and it will automatically be animated when the child's size changes

Or if you want separate widgets with separate sizes, you can use the `AnimatedSwitcher` widget and change its child widget

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Example> createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  bool largeSize = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: FlutterLogo(size: largeSize ? 300 : 200),
          ),
          AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
            child: largeSize ? const FlutterLogo(size: 300) : const FlutterLogo(size: 200),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() => largeSize = !largeSize),
            child: const Text('Toggle Size'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can checkout working code in this dartpad:
https://dartpad.dev/31452b543c6fd35ab2e65ac7c511919d

[This is the official video for the `AnimatedSwitcher` widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2W7POjFb88g)